# Giving a time series input to Pytorch-LSTM using a Batch size of 128

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a dataset of n training samples (Where X matrix = n * 30 * 20) where 30 is the number of sequences, 20 is the number of features. I am using categorical cross-entropy loss since this is a classification task. My input matrix is of shape 10000 *30 * 20 and target matrix is 1000 * 1. I was wondering what is the correct way to give the input to the LSTM. My entire code is attached below.

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.utils.data as data
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.utils.data as utils
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable

class MyData(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self,X,y,transform=None, target_transform=None):
        self.data = X
        self.targets = y
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform= target_transform
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        item, target = self.data[index], self.targets[index]
        item = torch.FloatTensor(item)
        target = torch.LongTensor([target])
        return item, target

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

class MyPredictor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_blocks=1, input_dim=22, batch_size=128, hidden_dim1=64, hidden_dim2=128, GPU=True):
        super(MyPredictor, self).__init__()
        self.batch_size= batch_size
        self.hidden_dim1=hidden_dim1
        self.hidden_dim2=hidden_dim2
        self.GPU=GPU

        self.lstm1 = nn.LSTM(input_dim,self.hidden_dim1,num_layers=2)
        self.lstm2 = nn.LSTM(self.hidden_dim1, self.hidden_dim2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim2, 256)
        self.fc2=nn.Linear(256,1)


    if self.GPU:
        self.hx1 = Variable(torch.zeros(30, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim1).cuda())
        self.cx1 = Variable(torch.zeros(30, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim1).cuda())
        self.hx2 = Variable(torch.zeros(30, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim2).cuda())
        self.cx2 = Variable(torch.zeros(30, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim2).cuda())
    else:
        self.hx1 = Variable(torch.zeros(30, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim1))
        self.cx1 = Variable(torch.zeros(30, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim1))
        self.hx2 = Variable(torch.zeros(30, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim2))
        self.cx2 = Variable(torch.zeros(30, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim2))

        self.hidden1=(self.hx1,self.cx1)
        self.hidden2=(self.hx2,self.cx2)

    def forward(self, x):

        out1, self.hidden1 = self.lstm1(x, self.hidden1)
        out2, self.hidden2 = self.lstm1(x, self.hidden2)
        out3=self.fc1(out2)
        out3= F.relu(out3)
        out4=self.fc2(out3)
        out=F.relu(out4)

        return out
```

Moreover, I am initializing the hidden and cell states as 1 * Batch_size * hidden size. However since I have 30 as sequence length, should it be 30 * batch_size * hidden size?

```
def train(epoch):
    print('\nEpoch: %d' % epoch)
    net.train()
    train_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    store=[]
    for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(trainloader):
        inputs, targets = inputs.to(device), targets.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        train_loss += loss.item()
        _, predicted = outputs.max(1)
        total += targets.size(0)
        correct += predicted.eq(targets).sum().item()

#         progress_bar(batch_idx, len(trainloader), 'Loss: %.3f | Acc: %.3f%% (%d/%d)'
#             % (train_loss/(batch_idx+1), 100.*correct/total, correct, total))
    print("Train->Epoch: ",epoch," Accuracy: ",100.*correct/total," Loss ",train_loss/len(trainloader))
    return[100.*correct/total,train_loss/len(trainloader)]


def test(epoch):
    global best_acc
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    net.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(testloader):
            inputs, targets = inputs.to(device), targets.to(device)
            outputs = net(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, targets)

            test_loss += loss.item()
            _, predicted = outputs.max(1)
            total += targets.size(0)
            correct += predicted.eq(targets).sum().item()

#             progress_bar(batch_idx, len(testloader), 'Loss: %.3f | Acc: %.3f%% (%d/%d)'
#                 % (test_loss/(batch_idx+1), 100.*correct/total, correct, total))

    print("Test->Epoch: ",epoch," Accuracy: ",100.*correct/total," Loss ",test_loss/len(testloader))
```

I am loading my inputs as below:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import numpy as np

#See if Gpu is available
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
net=MyPredictor()      
net = net.to(device)
GPU=False
if device == 'cuda':
    net = torch.nn.DataParallel(net)
    cudnn.benchmark = True
    GPU= True

#optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

#Load the datset


X, y = joblib.load("/app/dhanush/lstm_training_data.pkl")
X_train=np.array(X[0:30000])
X_test=np.array(X[30000:])
y_train= np.array(y[0:30000])
y_test= np.array(y[30000:])

print (X_train.shape)
print (y_train.shape)

trainset = MyData(X_train,y_train)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=128, shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

testset = MyData(X_test, y_test)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=128, shuffle=False, num_workers=2)


for epoch in range(0, 21):
    train(epoch)
    test(epoch)
```

I get the below shape mismatch error. I definitely think it has something to do with my input tensors or the way I am initializing my hidden states. Also, I am not sure if my input to the first fully connected layer is correct. Should I give only the last hidden state output from the LSTM 2 `(self.hx2[-1]?)`

On reading other posts, I see that for 2D inputs, you are sometimes asked to reshape to `(sequence * batch size * feature)` for direct input to LSTM. How does this work ?

And most important I get the below error :

```
RuntimeError: Expected hidden[0] size (1, 30, 64), got (30, 128, 64)
```

I understand this is all a lot but my goal here is to provide as much information as possible. I have read other posts, sample GitHub codes but most of them deal with using an embedding later which I don't want to use.

Comment: If I use batch_first=True, i get the below error: Expected hidden[0] size (1, 64, 64), got (1, 128, 64)

Comment: if you set batch_first=True, then your first dimension must be batch_size.
I would give the input as
bs,seq_len,no_of_features